# Free Photo editor software availablity in ubuntu

Tags: photo

Does Ubuntu have any free photo editor software? I am using Ubuntu and sometime for my work I have to edit pictures. I want to know if any software available in free version

Answer (score 3):

it depends on what you want to do; I mean you can use Shotwell Viewer that allows you to do a minimal set of modifications and comes with Ubuntu, or - if you need something more professional - you can install Gimp.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you wanted to know about Open Source Photo Editing Software can be found on the website shown below.

Great website with some very knowledgeable and helpful people.

I tend to user Rawtherapee and Darktable as my rawfile editors and GIMP for retouching. All three editors are best in class in my opinion.

https://pixls.us/